# Index page rendering the entire Event object. - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have started a new app and I'm setting up all the basic CRUD operations. I have a `Event` table and I'm trying to render all the events to an index page. All I want to render is the event name and description. Right now the name and description render but so does the entire event object? That's strange to me because I'm going through each object a picking out what I want to display. I'll show my code for clarity.

VIEW:

```
<%= @event.each do |e| %>
  <%= e.name %>
  <%= e.description %>
<% end %>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @event = Event.all
  end
end
```

SCREENSHOT:

[image]

FYI: I'm using the rails_admin gem. Any ideas on why the entire object is rendering would be greate thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have syntax error** 
Just remove the `<%=` from your first line and only `<%` then problem solved.
Now you should have:

```
<% @event.each do |e| %>
<%= e.name %>
<%= e.description %>
<% end %>
```

Meaning of <%= is to print and you printed entire object.